# wifi hiding itself after updating system

Tags: wireless

I had 15.04 then did a update, the wifi became hidden and cant be accessed (it's still there just hidden) 
I did a complete install of 14.04 (lost my 15.04 upgrades)  The package worked fine untill I did security and other updates, the wifi disappeared when I restarted the system (I have done this step about 6 times now, same thing, I have tried to only download security updates in increments trying to find a culprit, same thing happens on reboot) The wifi is still there, just hidden I have tried connecting from the terminal, no go.
The wifi is there if I just run the live CD

Is it a update gremlin???

Comment: What do you mean "Wifi is hidden"? Do you mean the network settings icon in the dash?

Answer (score 0):

wifi icon is empty (no curved lines), mouse over the wifi icon and it says "disconnected", left click and open network icon and my wifi connection is not there and under "wifi networks" it says "disconnected" but click on "connect to hidden wifi network" the box comes up, click "connection" and there is my wifi ssid but it still won't connect after following the prompts..............reinstall the system to before the updates and wifi is a'ok ............ I have recently downloaded 15.10 and run the "live desktop" It doesn't have a wifi connection "at all" so I'm thinking it's maybe my usb wifi dongle ???? (belkin)   I might have to get a new wifi card or go buy a cable ;0( ............(this is all on a desktop not a lappy)